# Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Firstly trying to connect Django + React. I was doing it by this tutorial [Click](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/). What I could find is the wrong order of . Maybe it causes because the wrong config webpack Thanks for any help!!

Full traceback

[image]

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>TEST</div>
  }
}

export default App
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Django REST with React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <!-- React will load here -->
    </div>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from './components/App'

ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById("root")
)
```

package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend/",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./src/index.js --output-path ./static/frontend/"
  },
```

Comment: How are you rendering App component?

Comment: Post rendered html please

Comment: @rockTheWorld have only 1 html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to render the React App at `#root` but it doesn't exist. It should be `app` instead.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Or if you want to use `#root`, replace `<div id="app">` with `<div id="root">` in `index.html`.

Comment: @randomname No worries. It happens.